# SO Careers: Remove extra gray underline from the 'most recent' navigation tab

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, design

The '[most recent](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=Javascript&location=san%20francisco&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles&sort=p)' sorting navigation tab shows a little extra gray underline to the *right* of it.

Here is a screenshot of the same:

> [image]

Upon doing inspect element, I see there is `margin-right: 4px;` for the `.tabNav>.-tab` class.

```
.tabNav>.-tab {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 4px; /* REMOVE THIS or set to 0px */
    padding-bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Commenting out `margin-right: 4px;` or setting it to `margin-right: 0px;` fixes the issue. Here is how it looks now:

> [image]

I know this is a very minor styling issue but fixing it will sure make it tidy.

Comment: Shouldn't this be *extended* to the right edge of the white background instead of completely cut off? Looks to me as if it should finish the grey line started from the left of the tabs.

Comment: @James did you mean to say nav-tab should be 'float:right'?

Comment: Well, specifically then: There is a gap between the grey line on the right on the right of the tab and where the white background ends a little further to the right. If you look at your 2nd image the grey line stopping on the vertical seems "unfinished".

Comment: @James take a look at this [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/WnyADa1.png) look at the above and below elements they all are aligned to right. As for 2nd image the grey line stopping on vertical seems "unfinished" goes, I'm not sure if SE's CSS code or browser default causing that. It would be good to know though.

Comment: Not a bug, this gives feeling of actual tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HackerKarma,

Thanks for the report. I spoke to our design team and they confirmed that this behavior is intentional. As such, we'll be retaining it as is.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Accepted.